# How to refer to matched part in regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am using the following code to search for a substring and print it out with a few characters before and after it. Somehow Perl takes issue with me using `$1` and complains about

> Use of uninitialized value `$1` in concatenation (.) or string.

I cannot figure out why...can you?

```
use List::Util qw[min max];
my $word = "test";
my $lines = "this is just a test to find something out";
my $context = 3;
while ($lines =~ m/\b$word\b/g ) { # as long as pattern is found...
    print "$word\ ";
    print "$1";
    print substr ($lines, max(pos($lines)-length($1)-$context, 0), length($1)+$context); # check: am I possibly violating any boundaries here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$1`, you are asking the code to use the first captured group from the regex and since your regex doesn't have any, well, that variable won't exist.

You can either refer to the whole match with `$&` or you add a capture group to your regex and keep using `$1`.

i.e. Either:

```
use List::Util qw[min max];
my $word = "test";
my $lines = "this is just a test to find something out";
my $context = 3;
while ($lines =~ m/\b$word\b/g ) { # as long as pattern is found...
    print "$word\ ";
    print "$&";
    print substr ($lines, max(pos($lines)-length($&)-$context, 0), length($&)+$context); # check: am I possibly violating any boundaries here
}
```

Or

```
use List::Util qw[min max];
my $word = "test";
my $lines = "this is just a test to find something out";
my $context = 3;
while ($lines =~ m/(\b$word\b)/g ) { # as long as pattern is found...
    print "$word\ ";
    print "$1";
    print substr ($lines, max(pos($lines)-length($1)-$context, 0), length($1)+$context); # check: am I possibly violating any boundaries here
}
```

Note: It doesn't matter whether you use `(\b$word\b)` or `(\b$word)\b` or `\b($word\b)` or `\b($word)\b` here because `\b` is a 'string' of 0 length.

Answer (score 3):

You have to capture `$word` into regex group `$1` by using parentheses,

```
while ($lines =~ m/\b($word)\b/g)
```

Comment: thanks! that works, can you explain a little more detailed why this needs to be done?

Comment: @user1769925 check group capturing => http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups This is basic regex feature.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to address a matched part in regex, put it in parenthes. Than you'll be able to address this mathced part via `$1` variable (for first pair of parenthes), `$2` (for the second pair) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The values `$1`, `$2` and so on hold the strings found by capture groups. When a match is performed all of these variables are set to undef. The code in the question does not have any capture groups and hence `$1` is never given a value, it is undefined.

Running the code below shows the effect. Initially `$1`, `$2` and `$3` are not defined. The first match sets `$1` and `$2` but not `$3`. The second match sets only `$1` but not that `$2` is cleared to be undefined. The third match has no capture groups and all three are undefined.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub show
{
    printf "\$1: %s\n", (defined $1 ? $1 : "-undef-");
    printf "\$2: %s\n", (defined $2 ? $2 : "-undef-");
    printf "\$3: %s\n", (defined $3 ? $3 : "-undef-");
    print "\n";
}

my $text = "abcdefghij";
show();

$text =~ m/ab(cd)ef(gh)ij/;  # First match
show();

$text =~ m/ab(cd)efghij/;  # Second match
show();

$text =~ m/abcdefghij/;  # Third match
show();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$1` will have no value unless you are actually capturing something.

You can adjust your boundary collection method to using lookahead and lookbehinds.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $lines = "this is just a test to find something out";
my $word = "test";
my $extra = 10;

while ($lines =~ m/(?:(?<=(.{$extra}))|(.{0,$extra}))\b(\Q$word\E)\b(?=(.{0,$extra}))/gs ) {
    my $pre = $1 // $2;
    my $word = $3;
    my $post = $4;
    print "'...$pre<$word>$post...'\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
'...is just a <test> to find s...'
```